# relief image - analysis of homogeneity, some algorithms?

Tags: image-processing

I have images of relief map. I would like to write a program that is able to analyze this map and identify typical situations shows in fig below.

[image: Relief maps]

Red color represents the lowest value, purple color - the highest. The region of interest is inside the white square. Do not pay attention to black and white circles - they serve for personal purposes not related to this question.

The color itself is not critical here, what is really crucial is the "form" of the maximum, i.e. the way it is located on the map. We can definitely tell the maximum on the left image while it is quite blurred in the right one (because it touches other areas which share similar color).

What I want my program to do is to distinguish between these two completely different cases, i.e. identify whether area inside white square is "reliable" or not (in terms of its "blurriness").

But I do not know what algorithms I should search for. Of course I can do this analysis manually comparing values at each point to others points, but I would like to use some established and robust algorithms if they exist.

Honestly speaking, I thought of using of the algorithms that find contours on binarized images, but it does not seem to be robust.

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I am using OpenCV, so if you know that something is already implemented in it it would be beneficent if you tell me.

**UPD**: I am not interested in situation only inside the white square - I would like to know what happens outside it as well and how it's compared to the region inside.

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but maybe you are looking for the degree of homogeneity within the white square, so you could calculate the variance/standard deviation in that region...

Comment: What I am looking for is kind of degree of homogeneity outside the square, compared to the one inside the square @MarkSetchell